# Issue with IIS...SERVER APPLICATION UNAVAILABLE

Tags: iis

My web application was running absolutely fine. Just 2 days back, I got an error saying.
SERVER APPLICATION UNAVAILABLE

I am pretty certain that nothing was changed on IIS. Unless my automatic Windows updates screwed it up completely.

My event viewer had zillions of following errors in Application category.

aspnet_wp.exe could not be started. The error code for the failure is C0000005. This error can be caused when the worker process account has insufficient rights to read the .NET Framework files. Please ensure that the .NET Framework is correctly installed and that the ACLs on the installation directory allow access to the configured account.

I reinstalled IIS. After installing, i ran aspnet_regiis -i for framework v2 and now it throws error saying - The application could not be initialized properly.

Any ideas what going on?

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your IIS_WPG group has read/write access to your deployment directory

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the application from the application pool and recreating it?  Have you customized any security settings?  What version of Windows/IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Alex,

By any chance do you have Symantec Endpoint Protection version 11.0.5002.333 running on your machines? I saw the same issue being mentioned on Symantec forums.

Just curious? As this update came out along the same time as the Windows Update KB 974417

Comment: Something to do with Symantec Endpoint Protection newer update. Check these links.

http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/net-framework-crashes-when-upgraded-client-sep-ru5

http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/aspnetwpexe-could-not-be-started-error-code-failure-c0000005-when-sep1105-installed#comment-3221691

Answer (score 0):

Check this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2009746.  That's caused by KB973917 froom the Dec 09 patching.  The error message is a bit different than yours though.

Also, if you recently updated your app pool identity, make sure that your custom app pool identity user is in the IIS_WPG group.

Answer (score 0):

I've been fighting this one as well.  Assuming it's a 11.0.5002.333 issue.  Considering rolling back to an earlier version if that's possible.